# Nyquist Sampling rate

Tags: signal, frequency, modulation, signal-processing, sampling

We have \$z(t)=\cos(100πt)\cos^2(500πt)\$ .

Find Nyquist sampling rate.

Well, I know that \$f_s=2f_{max}\$. My main problem is that I am not entirely sure if I could re-write the above signal as: \$z(t)=(2π50t)\cos^2(2π250t)\$, and say that \$f_{max}=250\$, therefore \$f_s=500\$Hz. That \$\cos^2(\cdot)\$ troubles me a bit. Anyone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [power reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula)

$$\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1 + \cos(2\theta)}{2} $$

on the \$\cos^2(\cdot)\$ term. You'll still have a \$\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\$ term but you can use the [product-to-sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

$$\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) = \frac{\cos(\theta - \phi) + \cos(\theta + \phi)}{2}$$

to convert it to a sum. That will give you a sum of cosines from which you can pick out the highest frequency.